# Clueless MC becomes extremely strong and trashes around martial sects

Tags: story-identification, manga

The MC of this Webtoon is a simple and clueless dude working in an inn. Later he learns sword arts and then goes to challenge martial sects one by one. He was wearing a mask and became famous because of his overwhelming victories.

Other details that could help identify the series:

1. The art style is very similar to "Champion’s Path to Murim" (especially how their faces look);
2. The MC doesn't have a family, but there was a woman without a husband who takes care of him. He also challenges other martial sects because she told him that her lost husband did that when he was young;
3. He was in love with one of the regulars at the inn he was working at. They later join the same sect and he becomes her senior;
4. Events take place in the Murim-themed world;
5. Earlier in the story some dudes come to challenge him but get beaten (he grabs interest of the beggar sect because of that I believe).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I've found it just now. It's ***[A Handsome Swordsman](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/5kzledd/a-handsome-swordsman)***.

> Moosung is an inn server with a huge crush on Soyeon, a beautiful woman from an influential family. Unfortunately, she’s only willing to marry… a very handsome swordsman. Now Moosung’s life mission is to become the best (and most handsome) martial artist in the world and win over Soyeon’s heart. So he starts training hard, but it’s not until he reads a book of secret martial arts skills that his true potential is magically unlocked. Can Moosung become a great martial artist, or will someone else swoop in and steal the love of his life?

Comment: Please don't forget to mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) by clicking on the check mark beneath the voting buttons. As this is a self-answer, though, you'll need to wait until 48 hours after the question was posted before the site will let you do that.